# Delphi Convert array of Byte to TBytes - UDP redirect?

Tags: delphi, casting, udp, type-conversion, delphi-xe3

```
procedure TForm1.UDPUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; 
                              AData: array of Byte; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  buffer : TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(buffer, Length(AData));
  buffer := @AData[0];
 end;
```

This code results in an access violation.

What would be the proper way to convert from **array of byte** to **TBytes** in Delphi XE3?

Comment: Shouldn't that `AData` parameter be of `TIdBytes` type ? ([`TUDPReadEvent`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TUDPReadEvent.html))

Comment: @TLama I think that's what emba screwed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy the buffer.

```
Count := Length(AData);
SetLength(buffer, Count);
if Count <> 0 then
  Move(AData[0], buffer[0], Length(AData));
```

I have a feeling that this part of Indy was screwed up by Embarcadero. Note the dubious passing of array by value. If I recall, the version on Indy from the repo is better.

Comment: [Embarcadero screwed up in XE3](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20120905.EN.aspx) only in that they changed the `AData` parameter from a dynamic array to an open array, but that does not change the fact that the wittrup's code to copy data from one array to another is just plain wrong to begin with.  So yes, use `Move()` to solve that.

Comment: @Arioch'The It does pass it by value. An what's more a copy is made.